# How to move objects by RMI?

Tags: java, rmi

Is there an easy, elegant and clever way to move objects between different RMI instances?

At the moment I would perform this task by cloning the object in the receiving RMI server and then destroying the original in the sending RMI client (or other way around when moving from RMI server A to RMI server B).

I guess, I will also have to clone and destroy all objects of the object?

Comment: what do you mean by Different RMI instances ?

Comment: RMI servers or clients running on the same or different machines.

Comment: can you give more context? why do you need to "destroy" the original object after you have a clone? RMI is "remote method invocation", meaning you have a proxy, which calls methods of the object on the other server. if you destroy it - there's nothing to call.

Comment: I want to move the object from machine A to B to free up memory on A or to shut it down. 

I have this architecture: A kind of "broker" (one or more) distributes data to RMI servers running on other machines, these store the objects and perform calculations on the objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your object implements "**Remote**" interface,  it is **passed by reference**.

If your object **doesn't** implements "**Remote**" interface, it is **passed by value**.

You have to take a decision depending on type of the object.

[Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/implementing.html)

Passing Objects in RMI

Arguments to or return values from remote methods can be of almost any type, including local objects, remote objects, and primitive data types.

The rules governing how arguments and return values are passed are as follows:

**Remote objects** are essentially passed by reference. A remote object reference is a stub, which is a client-side proxy that implements the complete set of remote interfaces that the remote object implements.

**Local objects** are passed by copy, using object serialization. By default, all fields are copied except fields that are marked static or transient. Default serialization behavior can be overridden on a class-by-class basis.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to clone the received object.

It is enough to create a reference to it.

The received object is already a copy (in the server b) of the original object used in the rmi call (in the server a).

Comment: But I want to move the object from A to B (i.e. to free storage on a machine or shut it down), so I guess I will have to clone it, as the original object is deconstructed or the entire remote instance will disappear.

Comment: @user2661619 *Non sequitur.* Just pass the object as a parameter and then forget about it.